# how to split string into two strings when it finds a number

Tags: c#, regex, string

So basically if I have `string a = "asd333";` I want to split this string into two strings

`string b = "asd"` and `string c = "333"`

for example `string a = "aaa 555";string[]b = a.Split(' ');` will make

`b[0]="aaa"` and `b[1] = "555"`

But this is not what i want i want to split string into two string withouth loosing characters and split it before a number

This is my code so far

```
 string text = textBox4.Text.ToString();

            char[] whitespace = new char[] { ' ','\t'  };
            string[] temp = text.Split(whitespace);
```

But i want to change it so string[] temp equals two string first is letters and second is numbers

Comment: so you are trying to remove spaces, then split by space ?

Comment: Why are you replacing `" "` with `string.Empty`? Why not just split on `" "`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's not the best method, but it works

```
    string a = "aaa333aaa333aaa22bb22bb1c1c1c";

    List<string> result = new List<string>();

    int lastSplitInedx = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length-1; i++)
    {
        if (char.IsLetter(a[i]) != char.IsLetter(a[i + 1]))
        {
            result.Add(a.Substring(lastSplitInedx, (i + 1) - lastSplitInedx));
            lastSplitInedx = i+1;
        }
        if (i+1 == a.Length-1)
        {
            result.Add(a.Substring(lastSplitInedx));
        }
    }

    foreach (string s in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the matched group from index 1 and 2.

String literals for use in programs:

C#

```
@"(\D+)\s*(\d+)"
```

Comment: Split by this regex `(?<=\D)\s*(?=\d)`. Here is [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vV8uQ3/1)

Answer (score -1):

Search for the integer in the string and split the string at that position

```
string a = "str123";
string b = string.Empty;
int val;

for (int i=0; i< a.Length; i++)
{
    if (Char.IsDigit(a[i]))
        b += a[i];
}

if (b.Length>0)
    val = int.Parse(b);
```